# $f(t)=\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} \hat{f}(n) e^{2\pi i n t}$ for $f\in L^{2}(\mathbb T)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let $f\in L^{2}(\mathbb T).$ Define $g(t):= \sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} \hat{f}(n) e^{2\pi i n t}, (t\in \mathbb T).$

Since $\hat{f} \in \ell^{2}(\mathbb Z),$ we note that $g\in L^{2}(\mathbb T).$

> **My Question is**: Can we say that: $f(t)=g(t)$ for all $t\in \mathbb T$  (pointwise equality) ? If yes, how to prove it? If not, any counter example?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to talk about pointwise equality in $L^2$. Perhaps you mean equal almost everywhere?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carleson%27s_theorem and also see a counterexample in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle#An_example:_pointwise_convergence_of_Fourier_series